# Tomcat AJP with Apache SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, apache2, tomcat7, orbeon

I have tomcat running behind Apache for the last 2 years and everything is going well. I'm using AJP connector (mod_proxy) to do this. However I now wish to enable SSL and when I create the vhost section for SSL and try access my application over SSL the tomcat section of my application doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what/where I've gone wrong. Below is the Apache vhost, tomcat server.xml and version numbers for various things.

Apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost REMOVED-IP:443>
        ServerAdmin sysadmin@XXXX.COM
        ServerName XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/applicationsvr/live
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/live_ssl_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/live_ssl_access.log common
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk.key
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk.co.uk.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk.intermediate.crt
        SSLEngine on
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth 2
        ProxyPass /app ajp://REMOVED-IP:8009/orbeon/
        ProxyPassReverse /app ajp://REMOVED-IP:8009/orbeon/
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="5000" keepAliveTimeout="5000"/>
```

Other:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2 x64
Kernel: 3.2.0-57
Apache: 2.2.22
Tomcat: 7.0.26
JVM Version: 1.6.0_27-b27
JVM Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

One of my clients that uses the application had an issue accessing the tomcat section of the application using port 8080 (default) and while testing with them we found that the config that has worked (non-ssl) was the only way to get it going. Is it possible to enable SSL in this configuration?

Comment: When it "doesn't work", what *does* it do? What do the logs say? Try disabling all of the client-cert stuff and just get basic SSL working first.

Comment: Normally without SSL orbeon produces an xform on the screen with populated data from an XML file stored in a mySQL database. With the SSL i get nothing displayed as if the mod_proxy isn't working at all. The rest of the application works under SSL as mentioned above so SSL is OK. It seems that SSL over AJP is not possible or I have it configured incorrectly. Everything in catalina.out looks ok as well as the localhost_access.log looks ok also.

Comment: SSL is terminated at the web server, so the SSL-over-AJP concern is not relevant. Blank screen = what kind of HTTP status code?

Comment: The HTTP part of the website is displayed but the tomcat bit isnt. I've uploaded an image here - http://i41.tinypic.com/2edys93.png

Comment: Without SSL I get an orbeon xform displayed in the area where the red error message is, however since running under SSL I get the error as per attached image, will I post Apache log and Catalina.out log snippets?

Comment: That error message in your image is entirely useless: it just says "something went wrong". I don't see anything that indicates SSL itself is not working. Can you connect to Tomcat through Apache httpd using an `https://` URL? If so, then httpd->Tomcat is working and something is wrong with your orbeon configuration.

Comment: OK, I'm going to look at the xforms today and see if they are hard coded to http:// this could be the case, will update with my findings.

Answer (score 2):

TO enable proxy execution while using SSL you should add "SSLProxyEngine on" to your config.